# Modal Pop-up not responding in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, modal-dialog

I have been working with three.js to create visualization involving satellites revolving around Earth. Currently I have two satellites that have been included as sprites in a scene and I am using Raycaster to detect clicks on these sprites. As soon as one of the satellites is clicked, a modal pop up displaying satellite information comes up. So far so good!. Now this pop-up has a x button that should close the pop-up when clicked. However this seems to be not working. Even hover does not seem to respond. I was hoping if someone could throw a little bit of light on the matter. My initial guess is that the canvas of the three.js scene is acting as a hinder. I have the following code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Detecting clicks on Sprite
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector3();

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function clickOnSprite(event) {
    console.log("CLICK!" + event.clientX + "," + event.clientY);

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(clickableObjects);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        intersects.forEach(function (element) {
        console.log("Intersection: " + element.object.id);
        element.object.material.color.set('#0bffff');
        clicked = !clicked; // This will temporarily stop the animation
        toggleModal();

    });
}   

} // Function ending

closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener('click', clickOnSprite, false);
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close-button">×</span>
        <h1>Satellite Information</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
.modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    width: 24rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.close-button {
    float: right;
    width: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.close-button:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
}
.show-modal {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}
```

Thanks for the help:)

Comment: We need a [mre] to help you fix this.

Comment: Limit the click event to `canvas`, not the full window. `renderer.domElement.addEventListener(...)`.

Comment: @ScieCode Thanks for looking into this. I tried your suggestion. But it doesn't seem to work. Can you tell me what the problem might be here?

Comment: Also @Chris G, I tried to use JS Fiddle to create minimal reproducible example. It did not seem to work.

Comment: The idea behind my suggestion was that, if your close button was exactly on top of one of clickable objects. It would trigger `toggleModal` twice and not close as expected.

Comment: Interesting. So I changed the position of the modal such that it would not intersect with an object. But still it did not work. An additional point to note is that when I hover over the 'x', the color does not change. So I think toggleModal being invoked twice is not the case here.

Comment: The same doesn't happen on JSFiddle? That's curious, do you mind sharing the link nonetheless?

Comment: Yes I believe it has to do with the fact that all my development is local. I did change the code such that it would reference online sources (uploaded the images to a site to generate link). But on execution only a white screen came. But I can still quickly put the code on JSFiddle. Might not work though.

Comment: make sure your modal and associated elements are z-index:999 so they are the top of all elements... add console messages to detect if it triggers.... inspect the element to see what listeners are on it. try closeButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ toggleModal(); console.log("closeListener") });